# error message 'init(accessToEntityTypes:)' is unavailable intializing EKEventStore

Tags: ios, swift, init, eventkit, reminders

I am following the instructions to initialize EKEventStore in [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/accessing_the_event_store), but I get a code time error at the following line:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore(accessToEntityTypes: .reminder)
```

The error message says:

> 'init(accessToEntityTypes:)' is unavailable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That document is wrong. If you look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore you will find no such initializer. It once existed on MacOS but never on iOS. Just call `EKEventStore()`.